# Part of string is lost when there is an accented English letter

Tags: php, unicode

I have a code to import a CSV file which is in Hungarian language to a MySQL table. Everything works fine until it encounters an accented character like ő,é etc within the string to be inserted. Any  characters after an accented letter is removed from the string and only the remaining is inserted to the table. For example, 'Artículos ErÃ³ticos' inserted as 'Art'

The code has nothing complex in it. The code to read is as given below

```
$content = file_get_contents($this->request->files['import']['tmp_name']);
$lines = explode("\n",$content);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    //Skip header row and empty lines
    if ($lineno != 1 && (!empty($line)))  {
        $fields = explode(";",$line);
```

A INSERT query is formed using `$fields` and inserted using mysql_query. An echo of the query in browser window shows the full string but database has only the partial string. I wonder if this is something to do with mysql setting or unicode string.

Comment: make sure you do `set names utf8` as you initialize the database connection

Comment: You may have to change encoding.

VISIT here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40516/sqlcmd-command-is-not-able-to-insert-accents

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

Use an `mbstring`

> mbstring provides multibyte specific string functions that help you
>   deal with multibyte encodings in PHP. In addition to that, mbstring
>   handles character encoding conversion between the possible encoding
>   pairs. mbstring is designed to handle Unicode-based encodings such as
>   UTF-8 and UCS-2 and many single-byte encodings for convenience (listed
>   below).
>   ...
>   mbstring is a non-default extension. This means it is not enabled by
>   default. You must explicitly enable the module with the configure
>   option.

- More on installing mbstring: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php
- PHP runtime configureation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php

**The reason:** PHP is old. When it first came out, UTF-8 was not widely used. And even though PHP 5 has been released, this legacy 'feature' still persists. In order to mitigate issues caused by this (for another example, the em-dash "—" will produce a similar issue with normal strings)

Comment: "Use an mbstring" *how* exactly?!

Comment: When I examined the mysql query log. It shows the query in full including the diacritic characters.  `INSERT INTO oc_category_description SET category_id = '5', language_id = '1', name = 'Artículos ErÃ³ticos', meta_keyword = '', meta_description = '', description = '' `  This makes it look like some thing to do with mysql setting